# Metal in Mac Catalyst fails with texture in volatile state

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, metal, mac-catalyst

When using a texture with a purgeability state of volatile my app crashes with this error:
"MTLDebugCommandBuffer lockPurgeableObjects]:2103: failed assertion `MTLResource  is in volatile or empty purgeable state at commit"

It works perfectly fine when I run the app by itself (not using the play button in Xcode but just clicking on the build icon) and also works when testing on iOS. This is a recent problem since updating to a newer version of Xcode recently. Is this something I can turn off so that the command buffers don't lock purgeable objects?

Answer (score 0):

It's working as intended. Let me explain.

First, the fact that you are not seeing this problem in your app is due to the fact that by default, apps that are launched from Xcode run with Metal Validation Layer. This is an API layer that sits between an actual API and your app and verifies that all the objects are in a consistent state and meet all the required preconditions and such. Apps run outside of Xcode don't have this layer enabled by default, because doing all the validation has its cost that you don't want to pass to the users, because Metal Validation Layer exists to be used during development. You can learn more about it by typing `man MetalValidation` in your terminal. You can also run your app with Validation enabled without Xcode, by prepending the invocation from the terminal with `MTL_DEBUG_LAYER=1`.

The fact that the app is not actually crashing and seems to work fine without validation layer does not necessarily mean that it will work in every case and on every platform. Some drivers may be more strict, some less. That's why Validation Layer exists.

Second, let's address what the actual problem is. Purgable state exists so that Metal can have an option of discarding some resources when the memory pressure on the system gets too high, instead of jetsaming your app. Only those resources that are marked `volatile` can be discarded in such a way.  But you can't just "set it and forget it". It's intended to be used for non-frequently used resources that are pretty big and can be discarded safely. The general pattern is described in [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/606/?time=2347) starting at around min 39. Basically, if you are going to use a volatile resource, you need to make sure that it wasn't already discarded and also make it non-volatile. You need to explicitly call `setPurgeableState` with a `nonVolatile` state and check if it returns `empty` (`setPurgeableState` returns the state the resource was in before the call). If it does, then the resource was discarded and you need to re-generate or reload the resource. If it didn't, then the resource is still there. You can safely use it in a command buffer, for example, and then set it back to `volatile` in a completion handler.

I would suggest watching that part of the video, because it goes more in depth.

Also, refer to an article [Reducing the Memory Footprint of Metal Apps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/reducing_the_memory_footprint_of_metal_apps)
, WWDC video [Debug GPU-side errors in Metal](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10616/)
 and [documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlresource/1515898-setpurgeablestate) for `setPurgableState`